# oracle: grouping on merged columns

Tags: oracle10g

I have a 2 tables `FIRST`

```
id,rl_no,adm_date,fees
1,123456,14-11-10,100
2,987654,10-11-12,30
3,4343,14-11-17,20
```

and `SECOND`

```
id,rollno,fare,type
1,123456,20,bs
5,634452,1000,bs
3,123456,900,bs
4,123456,700,bs
```

My requirement is twofold,
**1, i first need to get all columns from both tables with common `rl_no`**. So i used:

```
SELECT a.ID,a.rl_no,a.adm_date,a.fees,b.rollno,b.fare,b.type FROM FIRST a 
    INNER JOIN 
        SECOND b ON a.rl_no = b.rollno
```

The output is like this:

```
id,rl_no,adm_date,fees,rollno,fare,type
1,123456,14-11-10,100,123456,20,bs
1,123456,10-11-12,100,123456,900,bs
1,123456,14-11-17,100,123456,700,bs
```

**2,Next i wanted to get the `sum(fare)` of those `rollno` that were common between the 2 tables and also whose `fare >= fees` from `FIRST` table group by rollno and id.**

My query is:

```
SELECT x.ID,x.rl_no,,x.adm_date,x.fees,x.rollno,x.type,sum(x.fare) as "fare" from (SELECT a.ID,a.rl_no,a.adm_date,a.fees,b.rollno,b.fare,b.type FROM FIRST a 
    INNER JOIN 
        SECOND b ON a.rl_no = b.rollno) x, FIRST y 
      WHERE x.rollno = y.rl_no AND x.fare >= y.fees AND x.type IS NOT NULL GROUP BY x.rollno,x.ID ;
```

But this is throwing in exceptions.

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

The expected output will be like this:

```
id,rollno,adm_date,fare,type
1,123456,14-11-10,1620,bs
```

So could someone care to show an oracle newbie what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a couple different problems here;

Firstly, you're trying to group by an x.ID column which doesn't exist; it looks like you'll want to add ID to the selected columns in your sub-query.

Secondly, when aggregating with GROUP BY, all selected columns need to be either listed in the GROUP BY statement or aggregated. If you're grouping by rollno and ID, what do you want to have happen to all the extra values for adm_date, fees, and type? Are those always going to be the same for each distinct rollno and ID pair?

If so, simply add them to the GROUP BY statement, ie,

```
GROUP BY adm_date, fees, type, rollno, ID
```

If not, you'll need to work out exactly how you want to select which one to be output; If you've got output like your example (adding in an ID column here)

```
ID,adm_date,fees,rollno,fare,type
1,14-11-10,100,123456,20,bs
1,10-11-12,100,123456,900,bs
1,14-11-17,100,123456,700,bs
```

Call that result set 'a'. If I run;

```
SELECT a.ID, a.rollno, SUM(a.fare) as total_fare 
FROM a 
GROUP BY a.ID, a.rollno
```

Then the result will be a single row;

```
ID,rollno,total_fare
1,123456,1620
```

So, if you also select the adm_date, fees, and type columns, oracle has no idea what you mean to do with them. You're not using them for grouping, and you're not telling oracle how you want to pick which one to use.

You could do something like

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       FIRST(a.adm_date) as first_adm_date, 
       FIRST(a.fees) as first_fees, 
       a.rollno, 
       SUM(a.fare) as total_fare, 
       FIRST(a.type) as first_type
FROM a 
GROUP BY a.ID, a.rollno
```

Which would give the result;

```
ID,first_adm_date,first_fees,rollno,total_fare,first_type
1,14-11-10,100,123456,1620,bs
```

I'm not sure if that's what you mean to do though.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. I applied the same in my query:`SELECT x.ID,FIRST(x.adm_date) as adm_date,x.rollno,SUM(x.fare) as fare,FIRST(x.type) as type from (SELECT a.ID,a.adm_date,b.rollno,b.fare,b.type FROM FIRST_TABLE a 
 INNER JOIN 
  SECOND_TABLE b ON a.rl_no = b.rollno) x, FIRST y 
      WHERE x.rollno = y.rl_no AND x.fare >= y.fees AND x.type IS NOT NULL GROUP BY x.rollno,x.ID ;` But i'm getting another exception `ORA-00904: "FIRST": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`. Could you tell what i'm doing wrong again?

Comment: OK, i believe its `FIRST_VALUE(x.adm_date)` rather than `FIRST(x.adm_date)`. Checking with this now

Comment: FIRST is an aggregate function, so it takes several rows worth of values and returns one value (the first one). FIRST_VALUE is an analytic function, and will return  the same number of rows as the input, just with the first value applied to all of them.

Comment: I really don't think you meant to use FIRST at all though; I was using that more as an example to point out how you might have a flaw in the logic behind your query.

Comment: `FIRST` is ok for my case. But i'm not able to understand why when i'm using `FIRST`, its throwing that exception. Could you shed some light into it?

Comment: It's probably complaining about this FIRST, not the aggregate functions: `x, FIRST y WHERE x.rollno = y.rl_no`. What's that meant to do?

Comment: that FIRST is the table name. I don't think that's the problem. What `x.rollno = y.rl_no` does is for each rollno that is present in `FIRST` it checks whether its(rollno) corresponding fare >= fees present in `FIRST` table. I hope you got what i'm doing.